# Is bind(this) necessary in Thinking in React tutorial example?

Tags: reactjs

Within React's [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) tutorial, in the creation of a ProductTable component, the table is initially created statically in part like this:

```
var ProductTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rows = [];
    var lastCategory = null;
    this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
      if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
        rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
  }
      rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
      lastCategory = product.category;
    });
   // return table
```

However, later in the example, the table is created as such:

```
var ProductTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rows = [];
    var lastCategory = null;
    this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
      if (product.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText) === -1 || (!product.stocked && this.props.inStockOnly)) {
        return;
      }
      if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
        rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
      }
      rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
      lastCategory = product.category;
    }.bind(this));  // <-- this is the question
   // return table
```

Why is binding necessary here? The context doesn't seem to have changed, so why would the context need to be bound?

Comment: Alternatively you can pass `this` as the second argument to `forEach` to achieve the same effect without creating another Function, which is what `bind` does. It'd be `.forEach(function() { ... }, this);`

Comment: Thanks, Ross! This is excellent. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, There is no use of `this.` while in the second, `this.props.inStockOnly` is used. I'm assuming that you know why the `bind(this)` is needed since it will bind to the class.

Answer (score 2):

That's beacuse `.forEach()` will have it's own context. So, if use use `this` within `forEach()` you may get unexpected error.

That's why you should `.bind()` the `forEach()` with the context of the component to use it's context within `forEach()`

The following example should illustrate this.

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

b = {
  a: function() {
    console.log(this)
  },
  b: function() {
    a.forEach(function() {
      console.log(this)
    })
  },
  c: function() {
    a.forEach(function() {
      console.log(this)
    }).bind(this)
  }
}
b.a()
b.b()
b.c()
```